# How to attach success handler to ajax proxy of Treestore in EXTJS 4?

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4

Below is my ajax call to the server which loads the store:

```
   function setUpStore(Id){
    store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    storeId:'jsonStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'fetchData.action?ID='+Id,
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        success : function(resp){
            alert("success!!!");
        }
    }
});
```

}

which calls the below java method which returns a JSON object:

public String fetchJSONObj(){

```
              HttpServletResponse res = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
              HttpServletRequest req  = ServletActionContext.getRequest();

    ID = (String) req.getParameter("ID");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    VendorVO root= ServiceHelper.getInstance().getService().getData(ID);


    Data = new ExtJsTreeWrapper();
    Data.setText(ID);
    Data.setId(ID);
    Data.getChildren().add(convertVOToExtJSWrapper(root));
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

After I get the response from the server, I do not get the alert mentioned in the success handler. Am I declaring it correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

proxy hasn't got a config option called success.

Given your code you can hook on the store's load event:

```
function setUpStore(Id){
    store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        storeId:'jsonStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'fetchData.action?ID='+Id,
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            },
        },
        listeners: {
           load: {
               fn: function() {
                   // Do something here.
               },
           },
           scope: this               
        }
    }
});
```

If you do manual load, you can also pass a callback as a parameter to the load function.